# Having trouble serving assets in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following file structure:

```
- server.js
- controllers
  - [...]
- public
  - utils
  - views
    - home
      - index.html
      - js
         - index.js
      - css
          - index.css
```

Then inside my `server.js`, I do this when the application starts:

`app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, "public") ));`

This is the logic inside my "home" route.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const publicViews = path.join(__dirname, "public", "views");

    res.sendFile("home/index.html", { root: publicViews });
  });
```

While `index.html` renders when I navigate to `localhost:{port}/`, `index.js` and `index.css` are not being found and returned by the server.

This is how I'm referencing them within `index.html`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">`

`<script src="./js/index.js"></script>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick comment: it looks like you're serving `public/views` but your data is under `public/views/home`

Comment: @DanielB.Chapman That seems to be the complete problem, while / serves the HTML from `public/views/home`, everything else is served from `public`

Comment: @LucaKiebel how do I make it so that everything else is also served from `public/views/home` ?

Comment: `app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, "public", "views", "home") ));` Otherwise you have to include the files as `src="/views/home/js/index.js"`

Comment: @jsdev17 `const publicViews = path.join(__dirname, "public", "views", "home")` Take a look at the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths As Luca suggests the `express.static` method is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more static folder

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'home')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Then it will be possible to use your templates like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home/index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And your assets will be accessible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to assign method specific routing instead of using static middleware for serving resources from `/public/utils/`.

```
app.use('/utils', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'utils')))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'views', 'home')))
```